# The argument wether if one doesnt pray one time is a kafir

Tags: salat, kufr

I was wondering whats the oponions among the scholors regarding the one who only misses one prayer everyday

Comment: Depends upon which prayer you miss, for example Fajr and Isha are most difficult to pray for Hypocrites as per Hadith.

Comment: It's zuhr prayer but I wanted to see the evidences on both sides of the scholors

Answer (score -1):

Kafir refers to a person who disbelieves in God as per Islam, or denies his authority, or rejects the tenets of Islam. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kafir)  You believe in prayer, but you are unable to perform it for any reason. So you are not a disbeliever. For the other part of your question, I did not get a result. I will try to search more.